# Smart lock like on Android?

Tags: login, lightdm, lock-screen, gdm

Is it possible to configure either LightDM or GDM to automatically log in when my laptop is connected to a certain WiFi? Or even better, to check my location regardless of what WiFi I use?

Comment: No idea, but it sounds like something you would use udev rules for - something I haven't explored yet. You could possibly write a small program and run it as a daemon as part of your startup. It could watch for the wifi connection to become active. The next problem would be what  to do about your passwords. You don't want them stored in the clear anywhere and if they end up on the command line, they will be visible in history.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer the question about the [Bluetooth functionality](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/108380/20651) that you put in the title. I don't understand how the remainder of your question about WiFi relates to that.

You can use [BlueProximity](http://blueproximity.sourceforge.net/index.html) to lock and unlock you desktop when a certain paired Bluetooth device is in range. Here is an [article](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=702372) about BlueProximity on the Ubuntu forums from 2008.